# Exclude subdomain from Rewritecond

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I didn't find a thread that had the same `RewriteCond` I currently have.

My root `.htaccess` is set up the following way, so it redirects and auto adds `www` to any URL that doesn't contain `www`:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(BadBot1|BadBot2) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

However, I want users to be able to access a subdomain - `sub.mydomain.com` , so this subdomain needs to get excluded.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub\. [NC]
```

Before:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: Clear your cache and try with other browser

Comment: Thanks, however, what can I do about previous visitors to my website? I can't get them to clear their cache. Or since it is a new subdomain, it is only my browser that cached it, since I tried accessing `sub.mydomain.com` before the new Rewrite?

Comment: what if there are multiple subdomains? i am just asking.

Comment: It's only a problem with your cache, before the new rule.

Comment: With multiple subdomains it's more complicated if you do not want to mention them all. Ask new question for that.